# Swift Mouse Left Click Listener

Tags: swift

I am wondering how I can get this function to work, I just don't understand how to get correct type for NSEvent or where I even find it using developer documentation.

func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent)

I am trying to make an IF Statement that prints "User has clicked mouse" within a console window.

I am not looking for you to solve this problem for me, I am just hoping that you can show me a way that I can solve this for myself using developer documentation, please don't just link me a copy paste thread from another stack overflow unless it teaches me how people are finding the information required to solve these problems.

I just don't understand what goes inside of the parameter (with event: NSEvent) or how you would even find this out without just copying someone else's work.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to override your view controller [`func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder/1524634-mousedown) method. Just make sure you dont change the method signature and include the override keyword and dont forget to call super.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    // ...
    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.mouseDown(with: event)
        print(#function)
        
    }
    override func rightMouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.rightMouseDown(with: event)
        print(#function)
    }
}
```

Comment: So this function can't be used with just a swift terminal application?

Comment: @BabyProgrammer Nope. There are protocols for detecting mouse actions in terminal apps, but they're very different https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/4f75u5/how_does_htop_gets_my_mouse_input_via_ssh/ What *exactly* are you trying to do?